# I am trying to install Hadoop 0.23 but its not getting installed

Tags: apache-2.2, hadoop, client-server

I am trying to install Hadoop 0.23 on my fedora 13 but its not getting installed.On web every were there is support for hadoop 0.20 installation.
I am trying installation from [here](http://www.crobak.org/2011/12/getting-started-with-apache-hadoop-0-23-0/).
Every time i am getting error ,

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.

I also have added JAVA_HOME in my .bashrc file for current user.
When i am doing echo $JAVA_HOME I can see it.

Can any one guide me how to install it, nice article or link will work. Or if there are some steps I need to follow?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: When installing it always ask for JAVA_HOME and if i am setting in my environment variables , its its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure `JAVA_HOME` in `hadoop-env.sh` located in `$HADOOP_INSTALL/hadoop/conf`.  See http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop for details.

Comment: BTW, the URL is for pre-0.23 release and Q was abt 0.23 release. I was able to run 0.23 without making any changes to the hadoop-env.sh. Not sure why it's not working for CodeBanger.

Comment: In 0.23 there is no hadoop-env.sh file in conf folder.In conf folder there is yarn-evn.sh,yarn-site.xml and slaves file.

Answer (score 0):

With hadoop-0.23, the default config directory for HDFS is `$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop`, which doesn't contain a `hadoop-env.sh` file by default. You should create `hadoop-env.sh` in this directory, if you haven't already, and set `JAVA_HOME` there.